# Number of teams that can be formed

Tags: combinatorics

There are $N$ states in a country and you are given the number of players $n_i$ from each of the $i$ states, $1 \leq i \leq N$. There is a rule that for any team to participate in the game, there should be exactly $M$ players in a team and no two player should be from same state. How many maximum teams can you form?

Comment: Exmaple: If $N = 4, M = 3$  and $n_1 = 2, n_2 = 4, n_3 = 3, n_4 = 6$, then $4$ teams can be formed.

Comment: In your example, you did not specify the number of players in the various states.

Comment: thanks Andre for point the mistake.

Comment: It seems to me that there are many more than $4$ possible teams. For example if we choose players from States $1,2,4$ there are $(2)(4)(6)$ ways to form the team. There are similar expressions for other choices of $3$ states, and then we add up. However, I may not be interpreting the question in the way it is intended.